# fetching array with where condition in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

how to fetch array where catid= "someid" ?

i did try this but didn't work

```
public function findCatArr($catid)
{
    $select = $this->getDbTable()->select();
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $select->from('photo',array('id','catid','pic','desc'
    ))->where("catid"." LIKE '%".$catid."%'");
    $row = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select);


    if (0 == count($row)) {
        return;
    }else{

        return $row->toArray();


        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you want:

```
->where('catid = ?', $catid);
```

If you really want to do a LIKE search, then it's:

```
->where('catid LIKE ?', '%'.$catid.'%');
```

but only use that if you need it, as a LIKE search is considerably slower than a straight indexed lookup.

If `$catid` is an array of IDs, then this should work:

```
->where('catid IN (?)', $catid);
```

Comment: Note the use of the placeholder (`?`) in the `where()` this is very important as many classes in `Zend_Db` no longer support the old syntax style with concatenated variables.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching an array in zend base on id

$select->where("catid = ?", $catid);

Based on LIKE search in Zend

$select->where("catid LIKE ?", '%'.$catid.'%');